# iFrame move page up to parent div / top

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, window, parent

I have an iFrame within a parent page the length of the content varies from page to page in the iFrame so I would like to have the page jump back up to the top in certain situations.

This works fine in IE where breadCrumb is the id of a div in the parent window.

```
<script>
window.parent.location = "#breadCrumb";
</script>
```

It jumps the page to the right spot and the url is the parentwindowurl.aspx#breadCrumb

However in Chrome and Firefox this does not work it changes the page to the url iFrameurl#breadCrumb which replaces the parent page and has no breadCrumb div.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work in Chrome and Firefox?
Or is there a better alternative I should be using?

Comment: FYI your script tags should be <script type='text/javascript'>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to the very top, it's easy

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop

```
window.parent.scrollTop(0);
```

sorry it might actually be

```
window.parent.document.body.scrollTop(0);
```

if not, please let me know the error

Comment: Can I simply put that between <script></script> in the iFrame somewhere?

Comment: I like SO but always feel rushed to answer some questions...think it should be window.parent.document.body.scrollTop(0);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
window.parent.location.href = "#breadCrumb";
```

Comment: That breaks it in IE like chrome and firefox it redirects the page to iFrameURL#breadCrumb.

Answer (score 0):

The location hash is normally used to scroll to an anchor tag with a matching name attribute, so you would need to have a tag like:

```
<a name="breadCrumb"></a>
```

in the parent frame in order to have the browser scroll to that content with a location hash.

I'm not familiar with this behavior on div tags; that might be an IE-specific feature.